# Why constraints are differ in simulator and device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, autolayout

This is a image took from Simulator:

[image]

This is the image took from iPhone

[image]

See the differences ,this problem only occurs for IPhone6

**Constraints I used:**

[image]

[image]

These constraints I fixed for my `UIScrollView`.

I hope someone solves my problem.

Comment: The images you provided are abstruse.

Comment: @KenanKarakecili see the gap between the yellow color layer and image

Comment: its increasing in iphone6 but simulator its working fine @KenanKarakecili

Comment: Please, explain your view hierarchy, what constaints you have there. Are you sure they are added for that specific size class? Could you show some more screenshots from the Interface Builder?

Comment: Simulator is iphone 6?

Comment: @the_UB yes ,wait guys i will give more screen shots

Comment: @Sulthan i was added one more screenshot

Comment: The top space constraint should be pinned to UIView not the Top layout guide.

Comment: @KenanKarakecili because of this problem happens ?

Comment: Try removing the height constraint and see what happens

Comment: @the_UB ok i will try bro ....